# Possible ways to convert predicted scores from PCA analysis?

Tags: pca

I have my predicted scores from PCA analysis, and my predicted scores have both negative and positive numbers. For instance, minimum value is - 4 and maximum value is 4. I plan to use the predicted score as an index for my research. I am wondering whether I should transform my predicted scores to 1- 10 scores or 0 - 1 and such to make the index looks nicer. In addition, why do both negative and positive numbers involved in predicted scores I got from PCA? Please share me readings related to rescaling or converted predicted scores from PCA if they exist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would appear that linking through many of the "Related" threads listed to the right would answer this question for you.

Comment: PCA is usually done on the centered data, which results in PCA scores being centered as well, i.e. the average over your principal component should be exactly zero. This of course means that there should be some positive and some negative values. You can transform your scores however you like, but without knowing what you are planning to do with this "index", it is hardly possible to give any recommendations.

Comment: Thanks @amoeba, I am planning to use the index I got from PCA as my dependent variable which is to be regressed against independent variable by panel estimation method. Please give any recommendations you have and your input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rescaling the mean, variance, and range of your index won't change your results substantively - it can make your indices more intuitive. I don't think there is a single, objective rescaling that is considered "best" - it would depend on your context, your audience, what you will eventually be modeling, etc.

There are risks to making your index appear something that it is not. For example, if you rescale from 0 to 100, it could nicely be interpreted as percentages, but that would be wrong of course. Or from 0 to 10, it could be interpreted similar to a test score, where 0 is the min and 10 is the maximum possible score, but again, that would be wrong. You could rescale the variance to be 1 (if it isn't already), where a unit increase in your regression means an increase in 1 standard deviation - that can be understood by some people, though non-technical folks often have trouble understanding what a standard deviation is. These are things to consider in doing your rescaling - again, I believe this is very context-specific.